# jQuery animated bars, don't run when in viewpoirt

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I've got an animated bars script that runs when the bars come into a viewport...

Utilising this JSFiddle > http://jsfiddle.net/9ybUv/

Can anyone assist in making it so it doesn't run the animation if the page loads with the Bars in view.

Currently, if the users refreshes/loads the page with the bars in view, it shows the bars finished state (which is fine) - but then when the user scrolls the animation runs again, which looks weird. - It doesn't happen if the user scrolls into the bars, the animation runs and ends, it only happens when a user loads/refreshes the page  on the bars.

Code:

```
$(function() {

var $meters = $(".meter > span");
var $section = $('#third');
var $queue = $({});

function loadDaBars() {
            $(".meter > span").each(function() {
                $(this)
                    .data("origWidth", $(this).width())
                    .width(0)
                    .animate({
                        width: $(this).data("origWidth")
                    }, 1200);
            });
}

$(document).bind('scroll', function(ev) {
    var scrollOffset = $(document).scrollTop();
    var containerOffset = $section.offset().top - window.innerHeight;
    if (scrollOffset > containerOffset) {
        loadDaBars();
        // unbind event not to load scrolsl again
        $(document).unbind('scroll');
    }
});

});
```

Comment: I do not know what you see. But if I have the bars in view and I refresh the page it just runs the animation. So please explain, how do you test, in which browser? Does perhaps other JS files conflict your animation?